# I tried sudo apt-get install mysql-server but got this error .mysql installation error: dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):

Tags: mysql

[I tried  sudo apt-get install mysql-server   but got this error .mysql installation error: dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTUMd.png)